# how to create new column from difference between two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, replace, oracle12c

I create new table using join,listagg etc. I determined two columns as follow using listagg function. That columns are included following information.

```
Listagg_1_Column | Listagg_2_Column
---------------- |-----------------
123,234,565,321  |  123,234
```

I want to add new column this table. New column is included difference between Listagg_1_Column and Listagg_2_Column as below

```
New_Column
----------
565,321
```

For this, i used `replace(Listagg_1_Column,Listagg_2_Column,'')` statement but i retrieved wrong consequences. How to get new column by changing query? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is comparing the listagg data really the best option to your business problem ? Would it not be easier to create a 3rd listagg column with only the intersect of the dataset of the first 2 listagg columns ? Not sure if that option is feasable in your case but it would definitely be a more "sql" like answer...

Comment: You can may be able to do this with conditional logic in your query, but you haven't provided enough information to know if that is the case.

Comment: I retreived consequence i want. Firstly, i diveded it into two parts the main query and difference between two columns was filtered by using minus function. It was used listagg function over found data, retreiving data was good result. Koen Lostrie was inspired me with comment. Thanks for precious his view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you have the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data ( col1, col2 ) AS
SELECT '123,234,565,321', '123,234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123,234,1123,2345', '123,234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123,565,321,234', '123,234' FROM DUAL
```

Then you can split the strings using `XMLTABLE` and use `MINUS` to find the differences between the two sets and collate the results into a collection then you can aggregate the collection:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG( column_value, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column_value )
         FROM   TABLE( d.new_col )
       ) AS new_col
FROM   (
  SELECT col1,
         col2,
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             ( SELECT TO_NUMBER( column_value )
               FROM   XMLTABLE( ('"' || REPLACE( d.col1, ',', '","' ) || '"') )
               MINUS
               SELECT TO_NUMBER( column_value )
               FROM   XMLTABLE( ('"' || REPLACE( d.col2, ',', '","' ) || '"') )
             )
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         ) AS new_col
  FROM   data d
) d;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> COL1              | COL2    | NEW_COL  
> :---------------- | :------ | :--------
> 123,234,565,321   | 123,234 | 321,565  
> 123,234,1123,2345 | 123,234 | 1123,2345
> 123,565,321,234   | 123,234 | 321,565
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=daeb8bab21a01fad6bb86d99d0ff81c4)*

Answer (score 0):

Here i convert two columns to two table .After that it is easy to find differences.

```sql
with xxx
     as (select '123,565,321,234' listagg_1_column,
                '123,234' listagg_2_column
           from DUAL)
  select listagg_1_column,
         listagg_2_column,
         LISTAGG (myrow, ',') within group (order by myrow) diff
    from (    select REGEXP_SUBSTR (listagg_1_column,
                                    '[^,]+',
                                    1,
                                    LEVEL)
                        myrow,
                     listagg_1_column,
                     listagg_2_column
                from xxx
          connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR (listagg_1_column,
                                    '[^,]+',
                                    1,
                                    LEVEL)
                        is not null) xx
   where xx.myrow not in (    select REGEXP_SUBSTR (listagg_2_column,
                                                    '[^,]+',
                                                    1,
                                                    LEVEL)
                                        myrow
                                from xxx
                          connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR (listagg_2_column,
                                                    '[^,]+',
                                                    1,
                                                    LEVEL)
                                        is not null)
group by listagg_1_column, listagg_2_column
```

The code above works for only one count.Here is for multirecord.

```sql
WITH data ( listagg_1_column, listagg_2_column ) 
     AS (SELECT '123,234,565,321', 
                '123,234' 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '123,234,1123,2345', 
                '123,234' 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '123,565,321,234', 
                '123,234' 
         FROM   dual 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT '123,565,321,234', 
                '321,565' 
         FROM   dual) 
SELECT listagg_1_column, 
       listagg_2_column, 
       Listagg (myrow, ',') 
         within GROUP (ORDER BY myrow ) diff 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Regexp_substr (xx.listagg_1_column, '+[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) 
                        myrow, 
                        xx.listagg_1_column, 
                        xx.listagg_2_column, 
                        Regexp_count (listagg_1_column, '[^,]+') 
                        a, 
                        LEVEL 
        FROM   data xx 
        CONNECT BY Regexp_count (listagg_1_column, '[^,]+') >= LEVEL 
        ORDER  BY listagg_1_column, 
                  LEVEL)xx 
WHERE  xx.myrow NOT IN (SELECT Regexp_substr (yy.listagg_2_column, '[^,]+', 1, 
                               LEVEL) 
                               myrow 
                        FROM   data yy 
                        WHERE  XX.listagg_1_column = YY.listagg_1_column 
                               AND XX.listagg_2_column = YY.listagg_2_column 
                        CONNECT BY Regexp_count (yy.listagg_2_column, '[^,]+') 
                                   >= LEVEL 
                              ) 
GROUP  BY listagg_1_column, 
          listagg_2_column
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ea702acf30488209bee8588e3eb674a)

Comment: This doesn't always work as you'd expect [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cf3ec169e5a6e97a0a7eef58a4e959ef).

Comment: You are right.Thanks for sharing.I assume i fix it.But i can not explain how to i do that.my mind went blank.